# Freezing a supercooled liquid: is there a name for this?

Tags: states-of-matter, cooling, freezing

A supercooled liquid, i.e. a liquid below its freezing point (e.g. water), can become solid quickly by a mechanical perturbation.

Is there an official name for this particular kind of phase transition, as for example we use "deposition" for gas-into-solid?

I've found many explanations about this process on google, but not a name for it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any reason to think that the process is different from normal freezing?

Comment: The thermodynamics and kinetics are quite different from those of normal freezing. That said, I don’t know of a more succinct and accurate  description than, say, “mechanically (shock-)induced supercooled freezing.”